# OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected

Tags: python, json, sockets

I'm trying to understand networking on python using the `socket` module, but I think the problem is that I don't really understand how a server or client actually functions.

**What I am trying to do:**

- Send a dictionary from the client to the server by turning it to a string first using JSON
- Make the server send back a message to the client to confirm they are connected

Server program

```
import socket
import json

HOST = '192.168.X.X'
PORT = 50034


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            new_data = data.decode()
            new_data = json.loads(data)
            print(new_data["Name"],"has connected from",addr)
            message = ("Hello %s welcome to the chat server" % new_data["Name"]).encode()
            s.sendall(message)
            if not data:
                conn.sendall(data)
```

Client program

```
import socket
import json

HOST = '192.168.X.X'
PORT = 50034

my_dict = {"Name":"Bob"}
jsn = json.dumps(my_dict)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    s.sendall((jsn).encode())
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
```

But I am getting the error:

> OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected

Why?

Comment: You are trying to send via the listening socket.

Comment: What is the listening socket? Is it the code inside the `with conn:`?

Comment: `s` is the listening socket, the one you called `listen()` on and accept from, and `s.send(...)` is where you try to send from it, and where you get this error.

Comment: So how would I send data outside the listening socket?

Comment: Same way you are reading it?

Answer (score 6):

In your server code, you need to change ...

```
s.sendall(message)
```

... to ...

```
conn.sendall(message)
```

This is because when you do ...

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

... `conn` is a ***new*** socket instance ***for that connection***. So that's the object you should use for sending and receiving data on that connection. Before you call `accept()` to accept a connection, you don't have a socket that's actually connected to anything.

Comment: Or afterwards. The listening socket is never connected.

Comment: @user207421 I clarified the wording.